# База данных: что лучше: много записей или много таблиц

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Что лучше много таблиц или одна огромная?
Пример: у меня есть сайт с сериалами, каждый сериал имеет от 10 до ≈100 серий, для каждой серии несколько озвучек. В бд хранится ссылка на видео с серией. Что лучше: добавить записи для всех сериалов в одну таблицу или для каждого сериала создавать отдельную таблицу?

Comment: Лучше нормализированная база данных с простроенными связями и таблицами по типам сущностей, а не по конкретным сущностям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас будет 1000 сериалов на сайте, вы точно запутаетесь в таблицах. Это плохой стиль архитектуры. Изменения в базе на более поздних этапах должны сводиться к минимуму. Нет ничего плохого в том, что будет много строк в таблице. Главное, выставьте индексы. Либо, если если вы предполагаете, что записей будет настолько много, что запросы начнут долго выполняться(хотя, при современных мощностях, плюс грамотно сделать кеширование - это маловероятно), то можете сделать несколько таблиц по категориям. Например, по десятилетиям, диапазон букв, страна. Но что действительно стоит вынести в отдельную таблицу - это переводы.